# Add boolean in java code to check table status conditions

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to iterate through a list of records of sdid in java. sdid records is set of record up to 8 records with the same sdid but need to check the status column of each sdid to see if its `PEND_ADD`, `PEND_DEL` AND `ACTIVE`.

So for the first condition: if the status is `PEND_ADD` or `PEND_DEL`. Then delete the records.

If status is `ACTIVE` only, then delete records.

If status is `ACTIVE`, `PEND_ADD` and/or `PEND_DEL`, then delete `PEND_ADD` and/or `PEND_DEL` and keep `ACTIVE`

```
        private void disconnectClassOfService(List<Integer> sdidList) throws Exception {

            if (sdidList == null || sdidList.isEmpty()){
                return;
            }

            logger.info("Start deleting sdid : " + sdidList);
            for (Integer sdid : sdidList ) {

                List<CosPolicy2Interface> cosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid = getCosPolicy2InterfaceDAO().getCosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid(sdid);
                if (cosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid != null && !cosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid.isEmpty()){
                    for (CosPolicy2Interface cosPolicySdid: cosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid){
                        if (cosPolicySdid.getStatus().equals("PEND_ADD") ){
                            getPersistMgr().delete(cosPolicySdid);
                        }
                        if (cosPolicySdid.getStatus().equals("PEND_DEL") ){
                            getPersistMgr().delete(cosPolicySdid);
                        }
                        if (cosPolicySdid.getStatus().equals("ACTIVE") ){
                            getPersistMgr().delete(cosPolicySdid);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

my hibernate query

```
            protected static final String queryBySdid = " SELECT * "
                + " FROM cos_policy2interface "
                + " WHERE  connection_type = 'SDID' AND connection_id = ?";

        @Override
        public List<CosPolicy2Interface> getCosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid(
                long sdid) throws Exception {
            EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
            CosPolicy2Interface CosPolicy2Interface = null;
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryBySdid, CosPolicy2Interface.class);
            query.setParameter(1, sdid);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<CosPolicy2Interface> cosPolicy2InterfaceList = query.getResultList();
            return cosPolicy2InterfaceList;
        }
```

example of table:

```
CosPolicy2Interface_id,connection_type, connection_id, status
29, 'SDID', 13538806, ACTIVE
30, 'SDID', 13538806, PEND_DEL
31, 'SDID', 13538806, ACTIVE
32, 'SDID', 13538806, PEND_ADD
33, 'SDID', 13538806, PEND_ADD
34, 'SDID', 13538806, ACTIVE

My logic will erased all of it since it will iterate one record at a time. Could I use a boolean? some thing like this how can I implemented.

1) Pen Add -> dont care delete (But set PendingFlag to true)  
2)Pend Del --> dont care delete (Set Pending Flag to true)  
3) Active --> Store them in a list to check later  
     Come out of the for-loop and check if pendingFlag is false and activeCosList is not empty --> delete them
```

Comment: This is confusing, in your `disconnectClassOfService ` method you try to delete each record and in last if condition you check to see if the record status is equal to all the status, when a record can have only one status.

Comment: yes your right it will never hit that condition. Its wrong I need to only keep `ACTIVE` .so in that example record `29`,`31`,`34` for connection_id `13538806` thats my sdid.  I want to keep. and delete the `'PEND_ADD` and `PEND_DEL`.

Comment: So then why are you deleting the entity with `ACTIVE` status in `disconnectClassOfService ` method if you don't want to delete that record?

Comment: Second condition "If status  ACTIVE only , then delete all ACTIVE."

Comment: Does this mean when you have `ACTIVE` in at least one of the records you want to delete all `ACTIVE` records ? Or if all records have `ACTIVE` status other than records that have `PEND_DEL ` and `PEND_ADD`, you want to delete all records ?

Comment: ONE SCENARIO - so if my List of cosPolicySdid has 6 records, 2 records for `PEND_ADD`, 2 for `PEND_DEL` and 2 for `ACTIVE`. I want to delete 4 records, the `PEND_DEL` and `PEND_ADD`, only keep 2 records `ACTIVE`. SECOND SCENARIO - another list of cosPolicySdid has 6 records of status all only `ACTIVE` then delete all records (which will delete all 'ACTIVE' records).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to modify your `disconnectClassOfService` method.

```
private void disconnectClassOfService(List<Integer> sdidList) throws Exception {

    if (sdidList == null || sdidList.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    logger.info("Start deleting sdid : " + sdidList);
    for (Integer sdid : sdidList) {

        List<CosPolicy2Interface> cosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid = getCosPolicy2InterfaceDAO().getCosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid(sdid);
        if (cosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid != null && !cosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid.isEmpty()) {

            List<CosPolicy2Interface> recordsACTIVE = new ArrayList<>();
            List<CosPolicy2Interface> recordsNonACTIVE = new ArrayList<>();

            for (CosPolicy2Interface cosPolicySdid : cosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid) {
                if (cosPolicySdid.getStatus().equals("PEND_ADD")) {
                    recordsNonACTIVE.add(cosPolicySdid);
                }
                if (cosPolicySdid.getStatus().equals("PEND_DEL")) {
                    recordsNonACTIVE.add(cosPolicySdid);
                }
                if (cosPolicySdid.getStatus().equals("ACTIVE")) {
                    recordsACTIVE.add(cosPolicySdid);
                }
            }
            if ((recordsACTIVE.size() == cosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid.size())) {
                getPersistMgr().deleteAll(cosPolicy2InterfaceBySdid);// Delete all records
            } else {
                // delete non active records
                getPersistMgr().deleteAll(recordsNonACTIVE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to delete records individually.

Comment: none of the records get deleted, it goes to the else statement. than I added in the else statement `getPersistMgr().delete(cosPolicySdid);` and it deleted all my records including `ACTIVE`, `PEND_ADD` and `PEND_DEL`

Comment: @Gio see the updated answer. Even though I don' t really know about all the scenarios you want to cover, this will give you the right direction. I updated the answer based on your original post's last comment.